# Battery discharging extremely quickly and wont charge

Tags: battery

I am recently having this problem where the battery life on my laptop drains very quickly to the point where I have about 15 minutes of life before it dies after a full charge. In addition, the battery will not charge at all. The laptop is very hot. It was not like this before and I would have about 3 hours or so. And I dual boot with windows and have no battery issues whatsoever there. Any solutions would be appreciated. I am thinking it is something with my graphics card running unnecessarily, but I'm not sure how to check this. Thank you for any help.

Comment: Please [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1385545/edit) the question and include 1. The model of your laptop, and 2. The version of Ubuntu you are using.

Comment: Battery charging is handled by the hardware -- Ubuntu merely reports the information passed to it from BIOS. If your laptop fails to charge, then the hardware is faulty. Not an Ubuntu-related problem.

Comment: "Laptop is very hot" - ask the manufacturer, and use the warranty. Or, take it to a professional laptop repair place, and they can probobly fix it. Of course, make sure to blow any dust out of the fans (ideally with compressed air, not a vacuum)

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this appears to be a hardware problem, not an Ubuntu problem.

Comment: 'this only happens in Ubuntu, not Windows' seems to indicate it's NOT just a hardware issue.  If the CPU/GPU load is extremely high to the point where it draws more power than supplied, this could happen, especially if you are not using the right power brick.  But the high load would be caused by Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

There is not much information to go off of as I do not have the model or Ubuntu version, but here are some general steps that might possible solve your problem.

Open the Terminal and run the command "sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall", if this is an error with graphics card drivers this could potentially fix it. Restart after this command.

I *assume* this laptop has an Nvidia graphics card and is trying to use the [Nouveau](https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/xserver-xorg-video-nouveau) driver. As this seems to happen a lot with that driver and newer Nvidia cards.

If the above hasn't solved your issue, try to install [TLP](https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/tlp), this can solve some battery issues on laptops, I don't recommend this on installs where everything is working correctly but this is a specific case. You can do this by running "sudo apt install tlp" and restarting.

If none of the above helps, then this issue is out of my knowledge. I would recommend contacting your manufacturer to see if they have any information on this. You mentioned that everything works correctly on Windows however, so this is unlikely to be a hardware damage issue and more likely to be a driver issue.